# Why is convex combination of p.g vectors a p.g vector?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $I \in C^{1}(E, \mathbb{R}) $, where $E$ is a banach space, so $v$ is a p.g vector for $I$ at $u \in E$ if:
$$ \left \| v \right \| \leq 2 \left \| I'(u) \right \|$$
$$ \left \| I'(u) \right \| ^{2} \leq I'(v)v$$
So, given $\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}{t_{i}v_{i}}$ a convex combination of p.g vectors $v_{1}, ...$ for $I$ at $u$, I can prove the first inequality, but I have failed 
 to prove the second.

Thanls in advance.

Comment: What stands `p.g.' for ?

Comment: Pseudo-gradient = p.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed because it is not true. Let $E=\mathbb R$, $I(u)=\frac12u^2$. Then
the set of all $v$ satisfying
$$
|v|\le 2 |I'(u)|, \ |I'(u)|^2 \le I'(v)v
$$
is not convex for $u=1$ (note $I'(v)=v$): It is 
$$
[-2,2]\cap \{ v: v^2 \ge 1\} = [-2,-1]\cup [1,2].
$$